# Change date from MM/DD/YYYY to mmddyyyy in Notepad/Notepad ++

Tags: date, format, notepad++, notepad

I am a novice at coding and running scripts and was wondering the following;

Context: I run scripts in one of my companies programs to create customer service tickets.

Question: Is it possible to automatically update the date for a line of code in a script to the current day's date in MMDDYYYY format?

As of now I manually go and change the date for each script every day.

EX of (part of) script:

send "TKTE/R02252016"

Is there a way to automatically update the "02252016" to the current day's date?

I currently use Notepad/Wordpad for the scripts but can get Notepad++ if this is a possibility.

Thank you for your time and insight.

Answer (score 0):

Within Notepad++, you can search by means of a regular expression.

Search for `TKTE/R\d{8}` and replace it with `TKTE/Rmmddyyyy`, where `mmddyyyy` is the current date.